# C Program constantly closes

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main(char name[31], int phone)
{
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("data.txt","w");

    if (file==NULL)
    {
        file=fopen("data.txt","w");
        printf("Name : ");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        printf("\nPhone number : ");
        scanf("%d",&phone);
        printf("Your booking number is : ");
        fprintf(file,"%s;%d\n",name,phone);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        file=fopen("data.txt","a");
        printf("Name : ");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        printf("\nPhone number : ");
        scanf("%d",&phone);
        fprintf(file,"%s;%d\n",name,phone);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

When I compile and run the program, the program asks for a name. After I input a name, an alert comes up and closes the program. The program used to work, but after restarting the computer it now has this new behaviour.

What might be wrong?

Comment: normally I would say you need to elaborate on what the exact error message was, but right now I'm just wondering what you think you're passing into main and how that's supposed to work.... Whatever you're doing... don't do that. Just declare a local int and array inside your function to store the values you read from the user

Comment: I agree with Mike.  That's not a standard C program.

Comment: I think this is the first time I see somebody using function parameter list for local variables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program has some fairly serious problems.

Smallest first - fix your formatting, please. You're making it harder for yourself to notice bugs. If you can't read your code, you can't debug it.

Next is your `main` function declaration:

```
main(char name[31], int phone)
```

This is not how you define `main`. Its definition must be this:

```
int main()
{
  //code here
}
```

I'm somewhat surprised that definition even compiles.

What you'll probably want to do instead is just declare `name` and `phone` as normal variables within `main`, just like you declared `file`.

EDIT: as pointed out by @Namfuak in the comments, `main` *can* take an alternate form:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //code here
}
```

In this form, `argc` holds the number of parameters passed on the command-line to your program, and `argv` holds the parameters themselves. However, you don't need this form, since you're getting user input from stdin. Just the parameter-less `int main()` version will suffice for your needs.

Moving on to your file access...

```
file=fopen("data.txt","w");

if (file==NULL)
{
  file=fopen("data.txt","w");
```

You're trying to open the file, and if it won't open you open it again? Don't do that, please. It's not a good idea; if the file won't open once, trying again won't do anything special for you.

Similarly,

```
else
{
  file=fopen("data.txt","a");
```

This really isn't a good idea either. If `file` isn't null, it means you managed to open the file successfully. Why are you trying to reopen it without closing it...?

What it looks to me like you're trying to do is test to see if the file exists, and append to it if it does, or create & open it if it doesn't. You just need to use the "a" flag, though, per the [fopen docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) (emphasis mine):

> append: Open file for output at the end of a file. Output operations always write data at the end of the file, expanding it. Repositioning operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) are ignored. **The file is created if it does not exist.**

So if you just open the file in append (`"a"`) mode and make sure `file` isn't null, you can safely write to it. Either it won't exist so you'll create it, or it'll exist and you'll open it.

Comment: +1 for providing a great answer to a rather unclear question.

Comment: Small gripe - `main` can also have the definition `main(int argc, char** argv)` (or `char* argv[]`), which is why his compiler is probably allowing it.  I tested it on g++ and it does compile, though it warns about the invalid main parameters, but since his are in the wrong order it seems it casting an `int` to the `char*` and a `char**` to the `int`, which means they segfault if you try anything with them.

Comment: @Namfuak Thanks for the critique. I'll edit my post to mention the alternate definition of `main`, although it's my humble opinion that op is better served sticking to the simple parameter-less version until they're more comfortable with the language.

Comment: what is double star '**' for instead of char* argv[] ?